# Bottom images load before top images on my website

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Here is an **important introduction** for the question:

- It is known that, HTML prioritizes and loads first top DOM elements and then bottom
  ones.
- In my website ALL the article images are loaded as background    div
  CSS images but...
- The css for this is used inline (in the HTML DOM, not in an
  external file), so it doesn't really make a difference - I think.
- I use owlcarousel.js

To begin with, forget about owl-carousel.js. Still website loads bottom images first. Example:

```
<?php include( 'myowlcarousel.php' ); ?> //Ignore that for now
<?php include( 'latest-posts.php' ); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php include('recommended.php'); ?>
```

Images of recomended.php load before images of sidebar that load before latest-posts. It should be the other way around.

As far as Owl-Carousel is concerned, it's normal that images load after the rest because of javascript. It's at the top of the front page though, so its critical to load faster than the others. Do you have any ideas of what I could do? I prioritized its script as much as possible, but that's not enough.

How can I prioritize loads as shown? ( top to bottom )

You can take a look at the website here: https://www.greekgeek.gr

Comment: You would have to preload them via styles in your header for example. For example `body::after{ position:absolute;width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden; z-index:-1;  content: url(img01.png) url(img02.png) url(img03.png) url(img04.png);}`. Because: carousel activates after DOM load.

Comment: @skobaljic That's an idea, but take note images are not static. They are post dependent. Recent posts change daily!

Comment: Create a dynamic css, that's easy to do.

Comment: How is the priority-queue tag relevant to this question?

Comment: Also, you didn't ask a question. Are you asking how to fix this so that images load from top, down?

Comment: @JimMischel Removed the tag and added a question. Thank you